# AI : evaluate mass of a spaceship via prod (exert force lightly) and sense change in its velocity

Tags: artificial-intelligence, game-physics

### Problem

I have to code AI to find mass of a spaceship in a game.
My AI can exert a little force `c` to the spaceship, to measure the mass via change of velocity.

However, my AI can access only current position of spaceship ,`x`, in every time-step.

Mass is not constant, but it is safe to assume that it will not change too fast.

**For simplicity :-**
Let the space be 1D, and has no gravity.
Timestep is always 1 second.

### Forces

There are many forces that exert on the spaceship currently, e.g. gravity, an automatic propulsion system controlled by an unknown AI, collision impulse, etc.

The summation of these forces is `b`, which depends on `t` (time).

Acceleration `a` for a certain timestep is calculated by a game-play formula which is out of my control:-
`a = (b+c)/m`       ................. (1)

The velocity `v` is updated as:-
 `v = vOld + a`       ................. (2)

The position `x` is updated as:-
 `x = xOld + v`       ................. (3)

The order of execution (1)-(3) is also unknown, i.e. AI should not rely on such order.

### My poor solution

I will exert `c0=0.001` for a few second and compare result against when I exert `c1=-0.001`.

I would assume that `b` and `m` are constant for the time period.

I calculate acceleration via :-

```
t   0   1   2   3  (Exert force `c0` at `t1`, `c1` at `t2`)
x   0   1   2   3  (The number are points in timeline that I sampling x.)
v     0   1   2    (v0=x1-x0, v1=x2-x1, ... )
a       0   1      (a0=v1-v0, ... )
```

Now I know acceleration of 2 points of timeline, and I can cache `c` because I am the one who exert it.

With `a = (b+c)/m`, with unknown `b` and `m` and known `a0`,`a1`,`c0` and `c1`:-
`a0 = (b+c0)/m`
`a1 = (b+c1)/m`

I can solve them to find `b` and `m`.

However, my assumption is wrong at the beginning.
`b` and `m` are actually not constants.

**This problem might be viewed in a more casual way :-**
Many persons are trying to lift a heavy rock.
I am one of them.
How can I measure the mass of the rock (with feeling from my hand) without interrupt them too much?

Comment: You can only solve if the unknown forces are constant. If so then observe for 1 second, change in v (velocity) is acceleration a1 (of unknown constant force) then apply force for 1 second and get change in velocity as acceleration a2. Your force will have contributed a = abs(a1-a2) then use f = ma (force=mass * acceleration) to find mass m=f/a. If the unknown forces are not constant you can only ever get an approximation by repeating above and getting the mean over many iterations.

Comment: @Blindman67 Why not post your comment as an answer? It's as good as it gets.

Comment: The approximation from my solution will be very wrong for a certain time-step when there is an external impulse.  In worst case, mass can be guessed by my algorithm as negative number.   Blindman64's trick can only alleviate it only a little bit, I am afraid.